# How to do the Multiline Sum in a textbox by using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to sum numbers from 2 text box and the result to a 3rd text box in a PDF Form
**(Property of text Boxes set to **multiline**)**

Tried the following code but it is not working to add the values and display the results in each row.

```
var values1 = this.getField("Text6").value.split("\n");
var values2 = this.getField("Text7").value.split("\n");

this.getField("Text8").value = (values1 + values2 );
```

Unfortunately this is not working.Can someone help me on this?

Expected output below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2feGJ.png)

Comment: Please provide more complete code, like a minimally working example using the snippet functionality so we can more easily help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're `split()`ing a string into arrays, you can't add arrays. You'll need to loop through the arrays to add each number.

Also, the array is an array of strings, because you got it from the value of a textarea, which is going to always return a string. You need to `parseInt()` the string in order to turn it into a number so it will add the numbers rather than concatenate a string.

```js
function getField(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

var values1 = this.getField("Text6").value.split("\n");
var values2 = this.getField("Text7").value.split("\n");


for(i = 0; i < values1.length; i++) {
  this.getField("txtSums").value += (parseInt(values1[i]) + parseInt(values2[i])) + "\n";
}
```

```html
<textarea id="Text6">1
2
3</textarea>
<br />
<br />
<textarea id="Text7">4
5
6</textarea>

<br /><br />

sums:<br />
<textarea id="txtSums"></textarea>
```

Comment: I am just wondering instead of Grand total (21) how to achieve the total for each rows?

Comment: Is your code in Java or JavaScript? That looks like Java... I gave you the answer in JavaScript as your question is tagged with JavaScript.

Comment: I am using JavaScript in PDF Form

Comment: I've updated my answer to show you how to have two sums from each textarea, then a sum of both of those as the total sum.

Comment: Sorry for this...Can you update the code to get the sum like  1+4 =5 ,2+5=7,3+6=9 up to the end

Comment: Just did, sorry, I didn't understand your requirement until I clicked that link to see the image.

Comment: My code doesn't check to be sure the arrays are the same length, and if they're not, there will be an error. You'll need to write that part yourself.

Comment: I have another issue here. when I am changing the value of text box 1 or text box 2 the sum is adding to the bottom of the previous once.Could you please help me how I can reset the sums if there is any change in value 1 or value 2?

Comment: The same way you set the value of the textarea - you set its `.value` to an empty string.

`this.getField("txtSums").value = "";`